# store multi images in mat file using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The bellow matlab code is to read 6 images from folder and save them in mat file 
then return to read the mat file and check the images inside it

the problem is that
just the last images stores in mat file

the problem is in save function::

what should I edit to make save function store all images that stored in result cell into mat file

```
%Generate mat file
srcFile = dir('C:\Users\Desktop\images\*.jpg');
result = cell(1,length(srcFile));
for i = 1 : length(srcFile)
    filename = strcat('C:\Users\Desktop\images\',srcFile(i).name);
    I = imread(filename);
    %figure, imshow(I);
    I = imresize(I,[128 128]);
    result{i} = I;  
    figure, imshow(result{i});
end

save images, result;



%Read mat file 
for j =1 :length(srcFile)
    filename = strcat('C:\Users\Desktop\images\',srcFile(j).name);
    I = imread(filename);
    a='I';
    input = load('images.mat',a);
    figure, imshow(input.(a));
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first loop, up to the `save`, is fine.

When you load the data, use `load('images.mat')` before the second loop. Then, you have back the `result` variable in your workspace and you iterate on it:

```
load('images.mat')
for j = 1:length(srcFile)
    figure, imshow(result{j});
end
```

What you have to remember is that your .mat file only contains the variables you saved, but you can't access them directly with `load`. You first load them, and then access the loaded variables (which have a different name from the file, usually).

Finally, if you want to check this code, you need to `clear` the workspace after the save, otherwise you may not notice that some of the variables you use are not there anymore (like the error you have got with `I`).